# Write items to a dictionary from a file python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to write lists from a file and define them to separate values in a dictionary. The text file would look something like this:

```
[12, 13, 14]
[87, 45, 32]
...
```

and then the dictionary would look something like this:

```
{"score_set0": [12, 13, 14], "score_set1": [87, 45, 32]...}
```

This is the code I have get so far, but it just returns an empty dictionary

```
def readScoresFile(fileAddr):
    dic = {}
    i = 0
    with open(fileAddr, "r") as f:
        x = len(f.readlines())
        for line in f:
            dic["score_set{}".format(x[i])] = line
            i += 1
    return dic
```

I am only programming at GCSE level (UK OCR syllabus if that helps) in year 10. Thanks for any help anyone can give

Also I am trying to do this without pickle module

Comment: `x` is a scalar (`len(...)`), yet you index it as `x[i]`

Comment: What's the point of a dictionary with numbered keys? Why not just use a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x = len(f.readlines())` consumed your whole file, so your subsequent loop over `f` is iterating an exhausted file handle, sees no remaining lines, and exists immediately.

There's zero need to pre-check the length here (and the only use you make of `x` is trying to index it, which makes no sense; you avoided a `TypeError` solely because the loop never ran), so just omit that and use `enumerate` to get the numbers as you go:

```
def readScoresFile(fileAddr):
    dic = {}
    with open(fileAddr, "r") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):  # Let enumerate manage the numbering for you
            dic["score_set{}".format(i)] = line  # If you're on 3.6+, dic[f'score_set{i}'] = line is nicer
    return dic
```

Note that this does not actually convert the input lines to `list`s of `int` (neither did your original code). If you want to do that, you can change:

```
dic[f'score_set{i}'] = line
```

to:

```
dic[f'score_set{i}'] = ast.literal_eval(line)  # Add import ast to top of file
```

to interpret the line as a Python literal, or:

```
dic[f'score_set{i}'] = json.loads(line)  # Add import json to top of file
```

to interpret each line as JSON (faster, but supports fewer Python types, and some legal Python literals are not legal JSON).

As a rule, you basically never want to use `.readlines()`; simply iterating over the file handle will get you the lines live and avoid a memory requirement proportionate to the size of the file. (Frankly, I'd have preferred if they'd gotten rid of it in Py3, since `list(f)` gets the same result if you really need it, and it doesn't create a visible method that encourages you to do "The Wrong Thing" so often).

By operating line-by-line, you eventually store all the *data*, but that's better than doubling the overhead by storing both the parsed data in the `dict` *and* all the string data it came from in the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to turn the lines into actual Python lists, I suggest using the `json` module.  (Another option would be `ast.literal_eval`, since the syntax happens to be the same in this case.)

```
import json

def read_scores_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return {
            f"score_set{i}": json.loads(line)
            for i, line in enumerate(f)
        }
```